# Google cloud composer get airflow webserver_id

Tags: python, rest, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a GCP project `my_project_id` containing a composer instance `my_project_id_cmpsr_id`. In ordeer to get access Airflow rest API I need to retrieve the so called `webserver_id`. So the GCP airflow web server url is of the form `{webserver-id}.appspot.com` as specified here in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf)

```
# This should be part of your webserver's URL:
# {tenant-project-id}.appspot.com
webserver_id = 'YOUR-TENANT-PROJECT'
```

**Is it possible to retrieve `webserver_id` like `fg8348538536e2df34-fd` by `project_id` and `composer_id`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, you can go to your Airflow UI, than `Admin -> Configuration`, and search for `base_url` key, which is your `webserver-id` (without `https://` and `.appspot.com` parts).

Another way to do so, is using the following command:

```
gcloud composer environments describe <ENVIRONMENT_NAME> --location <LOCATION>
```

And you will be able to see `config: -> airflowUri` variable.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the values required with Python by running the code example on the [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf) and then modifiy it to return the webserver_id and client_id:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests
import requests
import six.moves.urllib.parse

project_id = getenv('GCP_PROJECT_ID')
location = getenv('LOCATION')
composer_environment = getenv('COMPOSER_ID')


def get_airflow_details():
    # Authenticate with Google Cloud.
    # See: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
    credentials, _ = google.auth.default(
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
    authed_session = google.auth.transport.requests.AuthorizedSession(
        credentials)

    environment_url = (
        'https://composer.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{}/locations/{}'
        '/environments/{}').format(project_id, location, composer_environment)
    composer_response = authed_session.request('GET', environment_url)
    environment_data = composer_response.json()
    airflow_uri = environment_data['config']['airflowUri']
    # The Composer environment response does not include the IAP client ID.
    # Make a second, unauthenticated HTTP request to the web server to get the
    # redirect URI.
    redirect_response = requests.get(airflow_uri, allow_redirects=False)
    redirect_location = redirect_response.headers['location']

    # Extract the client_id query parameter from the redirect.
    parsed = six.moves.urllib.parse.urlparse(redirect_location)
    query_string = six.moves.urllib.parse.parse_qs(parsed.query)
    client_id = (query_string['client_id'][0])
    
    return client_id, airflow_uri



def main():

    get_airflow_details()
    
    client_id = (get_airflow_details()[0])
    airflow_uri = (get_airflow_details()[1])
    print(client_id)
    print(airflow_uri)

    return 'Script has run without errors !!'

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```bash
gcloud composer environments describe "$COMPOSER_ENV" \
    --location "$LOCATION" \
    --project "$PROJECT" \
    --format "value(config.airflowUri)"
```